# Разбор URL с помощью parse_url

Tags: php, url

Задание:

> Сформировать список, хранящий разбор
> URL по его свойствам: протокол, порт,
> хост, путь, ресурс, слова запроса и
> вывести на печать в виде
> «Название/Значение»

Я использую функцию `parse_url`, но немного не понимаю, я недавно открыла PHP. Может кто мне объяснить насчет разбора URL: что такое "протокол, порт, хост, путь, ресурс, слова запроса"?
Протокол, вроде, - это http, хост - понятно, насчет остального теряюсь. Их можно вывести с помощью `parse_url` и какой должен быть адрес? Если можно, с примерами объясните.

По заданному URL

> http://www.scriptol.com/how-to/parsing-url.php#content

Мне выдает только

> Array (  [scheme] => http  [host] =>
> www.scriptol.com  [path] =>
> /how-to/parsing-url.php  [fragment] =>
> content )

Код PHP:

```
 $url = "http://www.scriptol.com/how-to/parsing-url.php#content";
 $arr = parse_url($url);
 print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве примера рассмотрим ссылку вида:

http://shurik:qwerty@my.site.com:9191/documents.php?documentId=128&type=pdf#content

Функция [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) возвращает массив данных в которых могут быть следующие ключи:

- scheme - ну тут понятно, http или https или чтото иное
- host - тут тоже понятно
- port - порт, к которому подключаемся (в url записывается после хоста через двоеточие (в данном случае это 9191))
- user - как правило не употребляется, но в данном случае user будет shurik. Записывается в начале хоста
- pass  - пароль, записывается вместе с user в данном случае qwerty
- path - путь к запрашиваемому файлу. В данном случае: /documents.php (всегда начинается с /)
- query - параметры запроса, записываются в url после "?" в данном случае documentId=128&type=pdf
- fragment - указатель на якорь, в данном случае content. Записывается после #

Надеюсь это помогло.

PS: >> Мне выдает только

ну и правильно, потому что другие аргументы у вас не заданы в вашей url

Comment: спасибо) просто я не совсем понимала, что это

Comment: Теперь мне задали дополнительно к этому сделать так, чтобы вывод был не строкой как здесь:

 Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => www.scriptol.com [path] => /how-to/parsing-url.php [fragment] => content )

а в столбик и с русскими названиями Протокол => http и т.д.
Эти названия меняются в самой функции parse_url? как поменять в ней ключи?

Comment: просто сделайте свой массив

    $url = parse_url('...');
    $arr = array(
      'Протокол' => $url['scheme'],
      'Хост' => $url['host'],
      // и так далее
      );

а, ну и вывести можно так:

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
      echo $key.' = '.$val.'<br />';

Comment: спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: А я бы порекомендовал сделать массив переводов:

    $t = array(
    'scheme' => 'Протокол',
    'host'  => 'Хост',
    ...
    );
    
    $url = parse_url('...');
    
    foreach ($url as $k => $v) {
     echo $t[$k].': '. $v.'<br/>';
    }

Comment: все не могу сдать, вот новый вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/44830/удалить-пустые-строки-в-файле-php
если не трудно - взгляните