# Регулярное выражение для получения домена без www и http

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне требуется создать регулярное выражение для превражения

1. http://site.ru/url_hegoto
2. www.site.ru**/url_hegoto
3. https://site.ru/url_hegoto

url_hegoto (параметры запроса например GET , ?go=back, его может и не быть)

Я хочу получить домен в таком виде site.ru

Делаю так:

```
  $url = 'http//google.ru/';
  preg_match("~//(.*?)/~", $url, $prega);
```

Скажите правильно ли регулярное выражение? или как будет правильнее?

Comment: Используйте функцию parse_url() для этого. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разбор URL с помощью parse\_url](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39800/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-url-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-parse-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо visman,теперь буду знать что есть такая полезная функция, теперь делаю так:

```
$url_parse = 'https://www.google.com/?q=test';
echo parse_url($url_parse, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: $url_parse = 'google.com/?q=test'; не проходит увы