# Составить регулярное выражение для извлечения части урла

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть url

> _http://domen.com/name

Необходимо извлечь часть:

> _http://domen.com/**name**

Помогите составить регулярное выражение.

Comment: parse_url не помогает, раз регулярка нужна? Можно еще проще пойти: выделить все что справа от последнего '/'.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разбор URL с помощью parse\_url](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39800/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-url-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-parse-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо регулярного выражения лучше использовать функцию [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php). Это будет существенно проще, чем возится с регулярными выражениями.

Для получения пути из URL можно использовать вот такой код:

```
echo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```